# Configuring Entity Framework in multiproject ASP Core 1 solution

Tags: entity-framework, configuration, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two projects: Web project that has connection string in its `appsetting.json` and Domain project that includes some repositories that implements business logic. Now i need to pass connection string from Web to Domain project. First i have got connection string value from config via method described in [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jun/03/Strongly-typed-AppSettings-Configuration-in-ASPNET-5), but how i can pass it into Domain? In previous version of ASP i could do it via ConfigurationManager, but now its imposible.

My DomainDbContext:

```
public class DomainDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) {
        builder.UseNpgsql(@"HardcodedConnectionString");
    }
}
```

and it used like

```
public List<SomeEntityDto> GetAll() {
    using(var context = new DomainDbContext()) {
        return AutoMapperHelper.Mapper.Map<List<SomeEntityDto>>(context.SomeEntities.ToList());
    }
}
```

In controller provider calls like

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
    private readonly AppSettings _settings;
    private readonly ISomeProvider _someProvider;
    public OrderController( IOptions<AppSettings> settings,
                            ISomeProvider someProvider) {
        _settings = settings.Value;
        _someProvider = someProvider;
    }
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View("Index", new SomeModel {
            someEntities = _someProvider.GetAll()
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First i have got connection string value from config via method described in this article, but how i can pass it into Domain?

You shouldn't have to. Also your domain layer is flawed if it needs `DbContext` in your domain. Domain has to be persistence ignorant. You get this abstraction via repositories usually. Otherwise your domain depends on your infrastructure.

Second, optimally you resolve all stuff via dependency injection, then all configuration stuff is up to the application and not a concern of your domain.

> In previous version of ASP i could do it via ConfigurationManager, but now its imposible

That still violates DDD, because `ConfigurationManager` is infrastructure (very very specific to ASP.NET) and do not belongs into your domain.

Ideally you just pass your `DbContext` into your provider class constructor. If you can't (your provider has longer lifetime than your DbContext), pass an factory that resolves the DbContext and then resolve it on demand.

```
using(var dbContext = this.dbContextFactory.Create()) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way contexts and EF in general is configured in EF7 (which is what I'm assuming you're using since you've mentioned .NET Core) has changed from previous versions. One way is to override the OnConfiguring method as you've already done. However the most common approach is to supply options to the DbContext constructor, which will allow you to configure EF in your web project and pass the connection string:

```
public class DomainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DomainDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    { }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs within your web project you can configure your DbContext as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DomainDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DomainDb"]));
}
```

You will need to tweak the "ConnectionStrings:DomainDb" based on appsettings.json. For the above to work it should look similar to this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DomainDb": "Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DomainDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  }
}
```